# Add some extra height to a div which has the equal height of a other div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the script down below that equals the height of two divs containing a spefific class. But in my case I need to add some extra height to an div.

I think this graphic explains it pretty good:

[image]

**My script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    //set the starting bigestHeight variable  
    var biggestHeight = 0;  
    //check each of them  
    $('.equal_height').each(function(){  
        //if the height of the current element is  
        //bigger then the current biggestHeight value  
        if($(this).height() > biggestHeight){  
            //update the biggestHeight with the  
            //height of the current elements  
            biggestHeight = $(this).height();  
        }  
    });  
    //when checking for biggestHeight is done set that  
    //height to all the elements  
    $('.equal_height').height(biggestHeight);  
});
```

Comment: Very simple: `$('.equal_height')[numberOfTarget].height(biggestHeight + 50);`

Comment: But where do you target that specific `div`? I thought about recommending you use `$('.equal_height').height(biggestHeight + 50);` but this will apply to all divs and if placed within the loop/each it will no doubt make following `div` `50px` bigger than the last. Not sure if that's what you are expecting or if you only want to alter one specific `div` from the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example, how to add extra height to the second `div` with class `equal_height`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var biggestHeight = 0;  
    $('.equal_height').each(function(){  
        if($(this).height() > biggestHeight){  
            biggestHeight = $(this).height();  
        }  
    });  
    $('.equal_height').each(function(i, item) {
      if (i === 1) {
        $(item).height(biggestHeight + 50);
      } 
    });
});
```

```css
.equal_height {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: violet;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="equal_height"></div>
<div class="equal_height"></div>
<div class="equal_height"></div>
```

And this script will make all your `div`s with class `equal_height` the same height (the largest height):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {   
    var biggestHeight = 0;  
    $('.equal_height').each(function(){  
        if($(this).height() > biggestHeight){  
            biggestHeight = $(this).height();  
        }  
    });  
    $('.equal_height').each(function(i, item) {
        $(item).height(biggestHeight);
    });
});
```

```css
.equal_height {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: violet;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#one {
  height: 50px;
}

#two {
  height: 25px;
}

#three {
  height: 75px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="equal_height" id="one"></div>
<div class="equal_height" id="two"></div>
<div class="equal_height" id="three"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pavel :-)